# CircleRadius (CustomMap renderer) only works if I use it in my InitializeComponent immediately and not inside a foreach loop xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

If I execute my CircleRadius inside my InitializeComponent immediately then I see it on the map, but if I want to create it once I load my data (loadPins function) then It does not appear on the map. It seems like it has to be loaded immediately or else it will not load. How can I adjust the code so it gets puts on hold until It gets added?

XAML and my customMap:

```
<local:CustomMap x:Name="mymap" MapType="Street"  IsShowingUser="true"/>
```

The Code:

```
public MapPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        loadPins ();
        /*
        var position = new Position (56.264945, 12.579809);
        mymap.Circle = new CustomCircle {
            Position = position,
            Radius = 2500
        };
        */ 
        // If I use the code above then I get a circleradius on the map.
    }
async void loadPins ()
    {   
        var getEnd = await phpApi.getEnd ();
        foreach (var currentItems in getEnd ["results"]) {
        latstring = currentItems ["Lat"].ToString ();
        lngstring = currentItems ["Lng"].ToString ();

        var storeLng = Double.Parse (lngstring, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        var storeLat = Double.Parse (latstring, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        var pin = new Pin ();
        pin.Position = new Position (storeLat, storeLng);
        pin.Label = "Test";
        pin.Address = "-";
        mymap.Circle = new CustomCircle {
                Position = pin.Position,
                Radius = 100000
        }; //I cannot see this one on the map.

        mymap.Pins.Add (pin);
        }
     }
```

This is my customMap:

```
public class CustomMap : Map
{
    public MapContentType ContentType { get; set; }
    public double CircleRadius { get; set; }

    public List<Position> Positions { get; set; }

    public CustomCircle Circle { get; set; }

    public CustomMap()
    {
        this.ContentType = MapContentType.Normal;
        this.CircleRadius = 500;
        this.Positions = new List<Position> ();
    }

}
```

And my CustomCircle:

```
public class CustomCircle
{
    public Position Position { get; set; }
    public double Radius { get; set; }
}
```

And my renderer:

```
public class CustomMapRendererCircle : MapRenderer
{
    MKCircleRenderer circleRenderer;

    protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<View> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged (e);

        if (e.OldElement != null) {
            var nativeMap = Control as MKMapView;
            nativeMap.OverlayRenderer = null;

            var nativeMapCircle = Control as MKMapView;
            nativeMapCircle.OverlayRenderer = null;
        }

        if (e.NewElement != null) {

            var formsMapCircle = (CustomMap)e.NewElement;
            var nativeMapCircle = Control as MKMapView;
            var circle = formsMapCircle.Circle;
            nativeMapCircle.OverlayRenderer = GetOverLayRendererTwo;

            if (circle != null) {

                var circleOverlay = MKCircle.Circle (new CoreLocation.CLLocationCoordinate2D (circle.Position.Latitude, circle.Position.Longitude), circle.Radius);
                nativeMapCircle.AddOverlay (circleOverlay);
            }
        }
    }

    MKOverlayRenderer GetOverLayRendererTwo (MKMapView mapView, IMKOverlay overlay)
    {
        if (circleRenderer == null) {
            circleRenderer = new MKCircleRenderer (overlay as MKCircle);
            circleRenderer.FillColor = UIColor.Green;
            circleRenderer.Alpha = 0.2f;
        }
        return circleRenderer;
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you might be facing a well known bug with iOS build 
try using this tweak,put the code which is not working inside a time for some delaying , for me this worked

```
if(Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Android)
                customMap.MoveToRegion (MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius (customMap.CustomPins [0].Pin.Position, Distance.FromMiles (55.0)));
                if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS) {
                    Device.StartTimer (TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds (500), () => {
                        customMap.MoveToRegion (MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius (customMap.CustomPins [0].Pin.Position, Distance.FromMiles (55.0)));
                        return false;
                    });
                }
            }
```

Comment: So this will fix the CircleRadius? If I put this in my Initializecomponent in my MapPage I get an error: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` on this line: `customMap.MoveToRegion (MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius (customMap.CustomPins [0].Pin.Position, Distance.FromMiles (55.0)));`

Comment: I am not working with the custompins currently by the way like i was on the last post. only a custommap and a "customcircle"

Comment: i suggest you that u upload ur project and requirement , i will fix it in free time ! 
as of now ! that code was there to give u a hint ! , that some time delaying the execution works with maps in iOS

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37544017/highlight-a-route-not-showing-on-custommap-when-it-is-not-loaded-immediately-i

The project is there inside my new post! I get the same thing when I work with a route.