# "Highlight a route" not showing on customMap when it is not loaded immediately in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

https://github.com/xamarin/recipes/tree/master/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/Maps/MapOverlay/Polyline/

https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/maps/map-overlay/polyline/

This project runs and works just fine but only If I have the customMap.RouteCoordinates inside the public MapPage, just like this:

```
public MapPage ()
{
    InitializeComponent ();

     customMap.RouteCoordinates.Add (new Position (37.797534, -122.401827));
     customMap.RouteCoordinates.Add (new Position (38.797534, -122.401827));
     customMap.RouteCoordinates.Add (new Position (39.797534, -122.401827));
     customMap.MoveToRegion (MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius (new Position (37.79752, -122.40183), Distance.FromMiles (1.0)));
}
```

If I try to gather data (with long, lat) via my db and then add the lines with those values the lines do not appear on the map (the pins themselves appear just fine):

```
    foreach (var currentItem in getStart["results"]) {

            latstring = currentItem ["Lat"].ToString ();
            lngstring = currentItem ["Lng"].ToString ();

            var storeLng = Double.Parse (lngstring, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            var storeLat = Double.Parse (latstring, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            var pin = new Pin ();
            pin.Position = new Position (storeLat, storeLng); 
            pin.Label = "test";
            pin.Address = "test";
            customMap.RouteCoordinates.Add (pin.Position); //here I add the pins different positions (there are like 3 of them) but I get no lines on the map.

            customMap.Pins.Add (pin);

        }

    }
```

In iOS this is the function where the routes are getting created. Is it here I have to adjust the code or is it elsewhere (if we are talking iOS):

```
MKOverlayRenderer GetOverlayRenderer (MKMapView mapView, IMKOverlay overlay)
{
    if (polylineRenderer == null) {
        polylineRenderer = new MKPolylineRenderer (overlay as MKPolyline);
        polylineRenderer.FillColor = UIColor.Blue;
        polylineRenderer.StrokeColor = UIColor.Red;
        polylineRenderer.LineWidth = 3;
        polylineRenderer.Alpha = 0.4f;
    }
    return polylineRenderer;
}
```

Comment: customMap.MoveToRegion (MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius (new Position (37.79752, -122.40183), Distance.FromMiles (1.0)));

where is this line in your code ???  , how will map know which portion to show you?

Comment: It is there as well and I have it in my project. I just had it removed to show the most important code but I added it now to the post.

Comment: i am looking to simulate the scenario you are facing then only i can help

Comment: Yes. Download this one: https://github.com/xamarin/recipes/tree/master/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/Maps/MapOverlay/Polyline/ it is the exact same i am using

Comment: i did , but this doesn't have the db thingwhich u r using

Comment: one sec, i will give u a code that will have the same effect. give me 3minutes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113421/discussion-between-saket-kumar-and-medvedo).

Comment: Still has not solved it. I tried to adjust this code right here: `public override MKOverlayView GetOverlayRenderer (MKMapView mapView, IMKOverlay overlayWrapper)` into a override but it says that: "there is no suitable method to override"

Comment: still have not found a solution to this. maybe this is a very rare bug @saketkumar

Comment: I didn't get time bro, but u can file a bug in bugzilla !

Comment: have you had the chance to look at this yet saket kumar?

Comment: @saketkumar i am facing the exact same issue right now with a current project. have any of you two made any progress with this?

Comment: i currently am not working on Xamarin,if u find solution update us here!

Comment: I also downloaded the n run it but problem is I am not able to see the highlighted route on the map in Android but it works in iOS any one have clue what to do?